# cannot change pch (point symbol) in R chart.Correlation

Tags: r, plot, performanceanalytics

I used the 'chart.Correlation' in 'performanceAnalytics' package to draw a correlation matrix plot. But I cannot change the point symbol with 'pch' parameter. Here is the code,

```
install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
library(PerformanceAnalytics)   
chart.Correlation(iris[1:4], histogram=TRUE, pch=3)
```

and what I got, [the correlation matrix plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Mwb.jpg). In fact, none of the passthru parameters work (e.g. labels, lty).

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Note that per the git hub ticket that was opened, the dots were removed in `version 1.5.2` to address warning messages. So note that while the below does solve the specific issue in question, it may cause others depending on what arguments are passed to the function.**

Fixed it, I just added `...` to the `pairs` calls:

```
chart.Correlation <- function (R, histogram = TRUE, method = c("pearson", "kendall", 
    "spearman"), ...) 
{
    x = checkData(R, method = "matrix")
    if (missing(method)) 
        method = method[1]
    panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", use = "pairwise.complete.obs", 
        method = "pearson", cex.cor, ...) {
        usr <- par("usr")
        on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
        r <- cor(x, y, use = use, method = method)
        txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
        txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep = "")
        if (missing(cex.cor)) 
            cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
        test <- cor.test(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method = method)
        Signif <- symnum(test$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
            cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", 
                "**", "*", ".", " "))
        text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * (abs(r) + 0.3)/1.3)
        text(0.8, 0.8, Signif, cex = cex, col = 2)
    }
    f <- function(t) {
        dnorm(t, mean = mean(x), sd = sd.xts(x))
    }
    dotargs <- list(...)
    dotargs$method <- NULL
    rm(method)
    hist.panel = function(x, ... = NULL) {
        par(new = TRUE)
        hist(x, col = "light gray", probability = TRUE, axes = FALSE, 
            main = "", breaks = "FD")
        lines(density(x, na.rm = TRUE), col = "red", lwd = 1)
        rug(x)
    }
    if (histogram) 
        pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor, 
            diag.panel = hist.panel, ...)
    else pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor, ...)
}
```

---

```
chart.Correlation(iris[1:4], histogram=TRUE, pch=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The "shapes" are also numerically coded. E. g. `pch = "+"` is equivalent to `pch = 3` or `pch = "."` =  `pch = 46`. See `?points` for a list. In your case you could try:

```
chart.Correlation(iris[1:4], histogram=TRUE, pch=3)
```

Comment: it's hard to guess without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks!! But this is all I have entered "chart.Correlation(iris[1:4], histogram=TRUE, pch=3)" . Because iris is the built in data. Will it count as a reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the retrospective specifying of the library! I tried the example in the help file `data(managers); chart.Correlation(managers[,1:8], histogram=TRUE, pch="+")` I can't see any `+` in the plot, can I? Seems to be kinda bug of the package I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying it! I agree, maybe that is a bug.

Comment: Welcome. I've opened [a ticket for this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/braverock/PerformanceAnalytics/issues/87).